# TypeError (String can't be coerced into Fixnum)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm getting a weird error. My app runs perfectly fine on my localhost but on my Heroku server it's giving this error: `TypeError (String can't be coerced into Fixnum):`

Here is my code:

```
@rep = rep_score(@u)
```

According to the logs that's the line throwing the error. I've commented it out and pushed the changes to Heroku and the app runs fine now.

Here is the `rep_score` method:

```
def rep_score(user)
 rep = 0
 user.badges.each do |b|
   rep = rep + b.rep_bonus
 end
 return rep
end
```

Also `rep_bonus` is an integer in the database.

Again this runs perfectly fine on localhost. Let me know what you think.

---

After removing `return` from the `rep_score` method it's working fine. I'm still new to Ruby, is there something wrong with putting `return`? It's habit from other languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby uses `+` as a combination tool for strings AND mathematical situations.

Simple fix:

```
def rep_score(user)
 rep = 0
 user.badges.each do |b|
   rep = rep + b.rep_bonus.to_i
 end
 return rep
end
```

`to_i` is changing `rep_bonus`, which is probably from the database model, from a string result into an integer. There are a few different typecasts you can set.  To name a few conversions:

- Array: `to_a`
- Float: `to_f`
- Integer: `to_i`
- String: `to_s`

Comment: Why do I need to typecast something when they are both integers? And that doesn't answer why it works on localhost.

Comment: Why is a universal question. I don't have the answer as to exactly Why, but it fixes the issue. I have found that integers being pulled from my databases, are not always set as the right type. Whether the issue is with my DB (I used MySQL) or not, I don't care to find out as a simple typecast fixes the entire issue.

Localhost and Production is a completely different environment. Could be millions of possibilities. Ruby versions different, gem ports not the same, platforms different, database versions are different... the list goes on and on, and I have 40 chars left to answer.

Comment: If you read my edit, you can see I fixed it with getting rid of the `return` before you answered this question. Is there a reason the return was causing the error?

Comment: I am new to ruby myself, but as far as I understand, "return" is optional. If no specific return is given, the last variable is returned. ex putting 'false' before 'end' would just return false. The only time I actually use return is when I need to 'break' a function or do a redirect in the controller "redirect_to root_path and return if/unless ..."